# Wire Inject two structs with an interface

Tags: go

There is a interface A and two structs B, C. B and C are implement A，I want to know how to use wire to inject them(B,C).

```
type A interface {
    Method1()
}

type B struct {
}

func NewB() *B {
    return &B{}
}

type C struct {
}

func NewC() *C {
    return &C{}
}
func (b *B) Method1() {
    println("b1")
}

func (c *C) Method1() {
    println("c1")

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "inject"? Your structs do not have any fields; what is there to inject?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.